# ASP.NET MVC 5 Validators Working After Validated Only

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to create a new part for a warehouse inventory database and my validators are not working correctly. This is what is happening.

Input: a         Result: blank (nothing)
Input: b         Result: blank (nothing)
Input: abc       Result: blank (nothing)
Input: abcdsfasd Result: blank (nothing)
Input: 123       Result: blank (passed)
Input: a         Result: REQ
Input: 12345     Result: REG EXP NOT MATCHING
Input: 123       Result: blank (passed)
Input: a         Result: REQ
Input: a123bc223 Result: REQ

So, I first have to either put a valid entry in (1-9999) or pass my 4 digit requirement to get the REG EXP to catch it, then I begin getting REQ Errors on any letters inputted and REG EXP NOT MATCHED for 5+ numbers.

Why is the REG EXP not hitting on letters?  Why does REQ only hit after a valid entry has been put in?  Of course if I hit submit, the REQ errors will occur but I want the REG EXP to hit as soon as they type "a" in the first time.

Model:

```
namespace Inventory.Database
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(InventoryPartsMetaData))]
    public partial class Table_Part_Warehouse
    {
    }

    public class InventoryPartsMetaData
    {
        [RegularExpression(@"[1-9][0-9]{0,3}",ErrorMessage = "REG EXP NOT MATCHED")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "REQ")]
        [DisplayName("CQ P/N")]
        public int C_CQPN { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
namespace Inventory.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class InventoryController : Controller
    {
        InventoryPartsContext db = new InventoryPartsContext();

        // GET: Parts
        public ActionResult Parts()
        {
            return View(db.Table_Part_Warehouse.ToList());
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult PartsCreate()
        {
            ViewBag.Count = db.Table_Part_Warehouse.Count() + 1;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PartsCreate(Table_Part_Warehouse tb_part_warehouse)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Table_Part_Warehouse.Add(tb_part_warehouse);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Parts");
            }
            return View(tb_part_warehouse);
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model Inventory.Database.Table_Part_Warehouse

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add New Part";
}

<h2>Add New Part</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.C_CQPN, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.C_CQPN, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = ViewBag.Count } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.C_CQPN, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Layout:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

Bundles:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

Comment: A regex on an `int`makes no sense. Use `[Range(1,9999)]`

Comment: Same story, still doesn't give error until I have input a valid entry.  Should it not give an error as soon as you input "a" or "abc".  It does not.  Once I input 123 hit tab, go back and delete it then type "a", it gives me the REQ error.  Makes no sense.

Comment: No. Validation is 'lazy' (its not initially triggered until you tab out - the `.blur()` event). Once it has been triggered, it will then be validated on every `.keyUp()` event)

Comment: The onblur event occurs when an object loses focus. The onblur event is most often used with form validation code (e.g. when the user leaves a form field).  So definitely after I have typed a valid code it works on .keyUp() event because i can type a and boom error msg pops up.  But if I reload the page, type a, tab out, there is no error msg.  Seems like the validator is using .keyUp() event only after it receives a valid entry.

Comment: No. It begins to use `.keyUp()` after any validation on any control in your form has been triggered. There is an article explaining it better than I can and when I get a chance I'll find it add a link

Comment: Could also be a firefox thing.  Using Internet Explorer, it does the same thing with error message but it will erase the field if its invalid.  Interesting.